# Track cell's value changement with data timestamp and values

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently working on a Demand Management tool on Excel VBA.

In Column G I have the demand's state (To-Do, Pending, Work in Progress, Completed) and in Column M I would like to automatically track the state's variation  when a user changes the value.

What I'm trying to obtain is something like "State changed from" & [state t] & "to" & [state t+1] & "on" & [timestamp] 
Example: "State changed from Work in Progress to Complete on 2019/09/05 - 15:30"

I'm a beginner at VBA so i have no idea where to start with this task...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach code to the sheet_change event. This is called every time the sheet changes. The code needs to check if the cell that changed is in your target column (G) and if so, write the appropriate value into the adjacent cell in column M. To attach code to an event it has to be in the sheet module of the appropriate sheet. Start the VB editor by pressing Alt-F11. In the project explorer double click on the appropriate sheet to open up the sheet module. Paste the following code into that module.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
if target.column = 7 then 'if column G then...
   Application.EnableEvents = false 'stop tracking changes
   Cells(target.row,13) = "State changed on " & format(date(),"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm")
   Application.EnableEvents = true 
End If
End Sub
```